# If I remove a property from Google Search Console and re-add it few days later, will it have any future bad impact for indexation / SEO?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console, google-search, search-engine-indexing

I made the mistake of adding a property without thinking of a few things I wanted to take care of before the final site goes live. I'm in the process of getting an SSL certificate, replacing some *Lorem Ipsum* with final text content for SEO, add a Gtag manager container, link the property to Google Analytics - add a few optimizations on-site.

I added the domain property (non-www, no prefix). I have not added any sitemap yet, however Google found 23 pages and I see some indexed.

Should I remove the property and add it again with most basic/important settings/content ready for indexing (https:// , more SEO content, gtag manager container, few optimizations here and there... ) - in just a few days?

Or it it ok to leave this first property as it is, and add improvements / fixes progressively ?

I have read somewhere that ***it's best practice to index the https:// version right from the start***, and I guess it's also right for all final texts / pages / content optimized. (it makes sense to me).

***Would I get a better benefit from re-adding*** the https property of the final optimized site, right from the start, in a few days?

Any thoughts or information about this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't remove your site from Google Search Console after you added it.  Removing the site isn't going to cause Google to forget about the site.  Google will continue to crawl the site and include pages in the Google search index even if you remove the site from Google Search Console.   The only thing that removing the site will do is remove your ability to see the stats that Google provides.

It is almost always fine to leave your site up while making improvements.   As soon as you have one page of content that could be useful to visitors, Google will usually include it in the search index.

It would be a good idea to fix the problems with your site quickly.   Lorum ipsum text, under construction notices, and lack of SSL are not good user experience.   Google is not likely to rank much of your site very well while those types of problems exist.

It would be better to take down pages with Lorum Ipsum rather than show them to Google for an extended period of time.   Getting to those in a few days should be fine, but don't let it go months.

When you get your HTTPS site up, make sure you redirect your HTTP URLs to HTTPS.  That is best practice anyway, but it is especially important because you let Googlebot see content on your HTTP URLs.

Adding Google tag manager and Analytics to your site would be nice to have for you, but shouldn't effect visitors or SEO.   There is no rush to do those before having your site listed in Google.

Comment: thank you for your clear reply. Much appreciated and good guidelines to follow - will do these fixes asap. Thanks a lot.